# Java jcurses проблема при запуске helloworld :-)

Tags: java, jni

Пытаюсь запустить приложение с использованием jcurses:

```
Window w = new Window(40, 20, true, "Hello World Window");
DefaultLayoutManager mgr = new DefaultLayoutManager();
mgr.bindToContainer(w.getRootPanel());
mgr.addWidget(
new Label("Hello World!", new CharColor(CharColor.WHITE, CharColor.GREEN)),
  0, 0, 40, 20,
  WidgetsConstants.ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
  WidgetsConstants.ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
w.show();
System.out.println("hey, run");
Thread.currentThread().sleep(50000);
w.close(); // reset the native console
```

Скачал отсюда jcurses-maven, собрал https://github.com/ctrueden/jcurses-maven.

Пытаюсь запустить приложение:

> java -Djava.library.path={X}/jcurces/jcurses-maven/target/ Runner.LifeRunner

Получаю ошибку:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: >jcurses/widgets/WidgetContainer

`jcurses/widgets/WidgetContainer.class` лежит здесь: 
`{X}/jcurces/jcurses-maven/target/`

Не могли бы Вы подсказать, в чем проблема?